# Unable to use jquery to change body, html position: fixed to position: absolute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'll just jump straight into it.

CSS:

```
body, html {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 0vh;
    position: fixed; 
    width: 100%;
}
```

jquery:

```
    $('.logos').click(function() {
        $('html, body').css({position: "absolute"});
 });
```

Reason why I initially set it to position: fixed was to disable scrolling on my main page but as I moved over to my secondary horizontal sliding pages, I'd like to unlock it so I could include scroll down info of the certain page.

Been searching around but nobody has the same problem has most of them are dealing with divs and the topics regarding body, html are not regarding this and merging them doesn't work. Any take on how to do this?

Comment: The code shown [works for me](https://jsfiddle.net/d6ourvma/) (in both Chrome and IE). Are you able to provide a demo that shows it *not* working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong try:

```
$('html, body').css('position', 'absolute');
```

Comment: Supplying an object whose properties specify the CSS properties to change is not wrong.

Comment: Maybe you should read [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/css/#css-properties).

Comment: Hi @AlanSutherland I've changed my code but my inspector still says that it's fixed instead of absolute :/

Comment: The OP's code [works](https://jsfiddle.net/d6ourvma/), just as the documentation says it will, so an answer that says that syntax is wrong is itself wrong.

Comment: calm down, why are you so angry?

Comment: Oh I got it to work! Thanks so much for the help! I had .appendTo(body) on it along with the wrong syntax! Thanks guys!

Comment: Why do you think I'm angry? Pointing out when an answer is wrong isn't a hostile act.

Comment: your tone is pretty hostile, maybe just supply your own answer rather than try shutdown mine?

Comment: My apologies, I did not intend to come across as hostile. I assumed you would not want to leave your answer standing when it clearly contradicts both the jQuery documentation and an [actual test case](https://jsfiddle.net/d6ourvma/). The OP's problem was in code not shown in the question, as indicated by their comment above about `.appendTo()`.